# Does the 2011 13" MacBook Air have a longer battery life than the old one?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My understanding is that the new MacBook Air 2011 is using a new Intel CPU that uses less power. I expected that should mean either longer battery life or a lighter computer, but I can't remember how much battery life they claimed the old one had...

Should I expect longer battery life from the new MacBook Air 2011?

Comment: It seems to be the same, from looking at [this](http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html) and [this](http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/30/macbook-air-2010-battery-life/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the previous MacBook Air 13" (2010) used a Core 2 Duo SL9400 or SL9600 which both have a TDP of 17W.

The new MacBook Air 13" (2011) uses an i5-2557M or i7-2677M which both have a TDP of 17W too.

I don't think we can say that these new CPU consume less power.

- [MacBook Air specifications on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air#Specifications)
- [MacBook Air 2010 CPUs on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#.22Penryn.22_.28low-voltage.2C_45_nm.2C_Small_Form_Factor.29)
- [MacBook Air 2011 i5 CPU on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#.22Sandy_Bridge.22_.2832_nm.29_3)
- [MacBook Air 2011 i7 CPU on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#.22Sandy_Bridge.22_.2832_nm.29_2)

My personnal opinion is that Apple tried to stick to the power consumption while boosting the performance by switching to a more modern architecture. I do not expect Apple engineers to work on switching architecture AND improving power consumption at the same time.

So to answer your question:

No, I would not expect a longer battery life with these new CPUs. Even a little reduction for those with an 11" MacBook Air because their CPU switched from 10W to 17W.

Comment: and what about the GPU?

Answer (score 3):

Apple hasn't changed the claims about battery life. 7 hours for the 13,3", 5 for the 11,6". It's a bit strange that according to Apple the batter life didn't change. Maybe we'll get a nice surprise.

Found it here: http://www.macrumors.com/2010/10/20/apple-announces-new-13-3-inch-and-11-6-inch-macbook-air-models-with-flash-storage/

Comment: Confirmed: compare http://web.archive.org/web/20101220204533/http://www.apple.com/macbookair/compare.html with http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html

Answer (score 0):

The old spec information for Macbook Air can be found here, as of July 20th: http://www.macmall.com/p/Apple-MacBook-Air/product~dpno~8233199~pdp.gcgabeg

New spec info: http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html